pmatop on Ubuntu 22.04
How to install pmatop on Ubuntu 22.04?
I've already installed pcp on Ubuntu:
apt install pcp                                                                 ✘  

07:01:58 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
pcp is already the newest version (5.3.6-1build1).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  dctrl-tools dkms libgsoap-2.8.117 libqb100 libumockdev0 libusbguard0 python3-resolvelib
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 19 not upgraded.

But it writes
pmatop: command not found


Use dpkg -L pcp to see if pmatop is part of the pcp package. Use dpkg -S pmatop to see which, if any, provides pmatop.
